# No linux-tools for stable kernel release

Tags: apt, kernel

I can't install and use perf tool on my linux server:

```
Linux vzu01-ubuntu 3.16.0-30-generic #40~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 15 17:43:14 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

root@vzu01-ubuntu:~# apt-get install linux-tools
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package linux-tools is a virtual package provided by:
  linux-tools-virtual-lts-vivid 3.19.0.22.9
  linux-tools-virtual-lts-utopic 3.16.0.43.34
  linux-tools-virtual 3.13.0.57.64
  linux-tools-lowlatency-lts-vivid 3.19.0.22.9
  linux-tools-lowlatency-lts-utopic 3.16.0.43.34
  linux-tools-lowlatency 3.13.0.57.64
  linux-tools-generic-lts-vivid 3.19.0.22.9
  linux-tools-generic-lts-utopic 3.16.0.43.34
  linux-tools-generic-lts-trusty 3.13.0.57.64
  linux-tools-generic-lts-saucy 3.13.0.57.64
  linux-tools-generic 3.13.0.57.64
You should explicitly select one to install.

E: Package 'linux-tools' has no installation candidate
```

I tried installing different packages but it wouldn't let me use perf anyway...
Could it be anything wrong with repository list?

Comment: Many years later, but I am experiencing the same frustration, that the mainline kernel PPA does not include the `tools` and `cloud-tools` packages. :(

Comment: @mikepurvis this particular question shouldn't have appeared if it was today. These days my needs are covered by `apt install linux-tools-common`

Comment: `linux-tools-common` is just the manpages and some pass-thru wrapper scripts, even in eoan. You still need the `linux-tools` package compiled for your specific kernel, which only seems to be available for the the supported kernels, not the mainline ones.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can install `linux-tools` this way.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-tools-generic-lts-utopic
```

But it looks that you never updated your system. Kernel is outdated. Run

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

That will get your kernel and other software up to date. Versions of `linux-image` and `linux-tools` will match after reboot.

Comment: this was done. It's not a question of how to install, it's the question what to install. The versions MUST coincide and they don't: root@vzu01-ubuntu:~# perf
WARNING: perf not found for kernel 3.16.0-30

  You may need to install the following packages for this specific kernel:
    linux-tools-3.16.0-30-generic
    linux-cloud-tools-3.16.0-30-generic

  You may also want to install one of the following packages to keep up to date:
    linux-tools-generic-lts-<series>
    linux-cloud-tools-generic-lts-<series>
root@vzu01-ubuntu:~#

Comment: You kernel is not upgraded. I will update the answer.

Comment: well, I install the system from a scratch 2 months ago. It was the latest stable release. update and dist-upgrade were just done as you advised. The kernel version is still 3.16.0-30 and perf from linux-tools-generic-lts-utopic does not match!

Comment: Did you reboot?

Comment: And it is not a good idea not to update the system.